# Heteroskedasticity robust standard errors using wbm() function from package 'panelr'

Tags: panel, standard-error

I'm using the package 'panelr' in order to use the within-between model through the function wbm(). Now I want to implement the heteroskedasticity robust standard errors for my coefficients, but I just know how to do it within the package 'plm'.

How can i get the heteroskedasticity robust standard errors for objects from the package 'panelr' like wbm()? Here's an example of my model:

```
model <- wbm(efic ~ faf + faf*alidep_SI + faf*alixun_SI + mun_tur_SI
             + disper + envell + distancia + priv + ideo2_E
             + fragmen_MIN + xenero_M + part + pib_pc | manco_SI, data = data)
summary(model)
```